# Advice on reading and problem material for Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, book-recommendation

I'm thinking of buying an algebraic number theory book so I can do problems.  Right now, I have this awesome set: https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/ of notes, but I want something to read and do practice problems at school.  The lecture notes are based on Daniel A. Marcus' ***Number Fields*** and I'm planning on getting that, but if anyone has any other recommendations, feel free to add.

Answer (score 2):

You *must* get:  ***Elementary number theory:  A Collection of problems with solutions*** by V K Krishnan (University Press).

My favorite number theory book is:  ***An illustrated theory of numbers*** by Martin Weissman (AMS), but it does not have problems, and thus doesn't fulfill your request.

Comment: $+1$ for *An illustrated theory of numbers* – its the first book I bought in paper form in ages, and it's a treat.

Comment: @joriki:  (Marty Weissman hosted my talk at UCSC a few years ago.)  If you liked his book, let me strongly recommend ***Visual group theory*** by Nathan Carter (AMS).  And on-line nobody surpasses Grant Sanderson, 3b1b (three blue, one brown).

Comment: Thanks for the additional recommendations. I can't say I "liked" it in the past tense – I'm still working through it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The lecture notes of J. S. Milne on algebraic number theory has exercises with solutions, see http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html,

appendix A: Solutions to the exercises.

Robert Ash's book on algebraic number theory, which can be found here:

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ANT.html

contains solutions to all the exercises.

I have the book *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory by Murty and Esmonde*, which is particularly good,and it gives good foundations for advanced texts.