# Book, or material recommendation to start with number theory.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I really do not know if this is the place to ask, if it isn't, I would appreciate if you steer me in the right direction.

So I am a math grad student dropout, sad but true. I really love math, and even though I will most likely not fulfill my dream of invetigating, I still want to learn. So after some time of mourning, I am rady to study math again.

I have basic knowledge of complex analysis, and all basic algebras (Rings, modules, Galoi theory, etc.).
considering this list of what seems to be areas relative to number theory:

What books would you recomend?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580943/.

Comment: @joriki I read that post, and I do not know if that is what I am looking for. It seems those books are for problem solving. I am interested in getting started with the theory. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it's not the same thing, that's why I didn't vote to close as a duplicate, just linked for info. But do take a look at *An illustrated theory of numbers* suggested in 
David G. Stork's answer – I got it based on that recommendation, and I like it a lot; I wouldn't say it's for problem solving.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite book——by far——on number theory is:  ***An illustrated theory of numbers*** by Martin Weissman.  This will help you understand and *think* about number theory.  However, it isn't comprehensive, and there are several key ideas that it omits because there are no natural visualizations of them.  So I would supplement this book with ***Elementary number theory and its application*** by Kenneth Rosen.

If you're working on your own, it is essential you solve problems.  Without a teacher, you'll likely need solutions.  For this reason I recommend the following two books:

***Introduction to number theory*** by Mathew Crawford, which has a nice ***Solution Manual***.

I also like ***Elementary number theory:  A collection of problems with solutions*** by V K Krishnan.  You won't *learn* number theory from Krishnan's book, but you'll learn to *solve problems*, which is of course essential for any deep understanding.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am going to take a little time to get to know your recommendations before I accept this answer, I hope that's ok. And yes, I am a math teacher (high school, middle school) and I could not agree more that problem solving is essential in truly understanding any mathematics.

Comment: Great book!! skipped the first few chapters but the book goes about pretty well. There's even a study guide in the preface, thanks for the recommendation.